# Automatically adjust range in VBA to the first empty column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A                 B         C         D        E          F
1                     2019-03   2019-04   2019-05   2019-06   2019-07
2    
3   Revenue             500       600
4   COGS                -40       -30
5   Gross Profit        460       570
6   
7   OPEX                -10       -12
8   Interests           -20       -50
9
8   EBT                 430       508
```

**Formulas:**

```
B5 = SUM(B3:B4)
C5 = SUM(C3:C4)
B10 = B5+B7+B8
C10 = C5+C7+C8
```

The spreadsheet shows the performance of a company per month.

Each time a new month is reached I want to copy the values from the last month to the new month. Therefore I developed the following `VBA` for the month `2019-05`:

```
Sub test()
Sheet1.Range("C5:C14").Copy
Sheet1.Range("D5:D14").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

Now my issue is that I would have to adjust the ranges wihtin the VBA each month manually to copy the values from the previous month. 
Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to tell the VBA which was the last non-empty month and then copy the values/formulas from this month into the next month.

Comment: `Sheet1.cells(5,columns.count).end(xltoleft).column` will give you last used column in row 5 so you could then use `Cells(r,c)` notation to refer to the correct range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the last used column of a row with the below code

```
Sub Last_Used_Column()
'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example
    Dim LastCol As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    MsgBox LastCol
End Sub
```

You can append the above code in your code and use the LastCol variable wherever you need.

Comment: Note that `.Column` returns a `Long` not an `Integer`. Therfore `Dim LastCol As Long`

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach

```
Sub test()

Dim c As Long

With Sheet1
    c = .Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'returns 3 if last column is C
    With Range(.Cells(5, c), .Cells(14, c))
        .Copy .Offset(, 1)
    End With
End With

End Sub
```