# Identify the first emtpy column within a certain range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A                 B         C         D        E          F         G        H
1                     2019-03   2019-04   2019-05   2019-06   2019-07   Total
2    
3   Revenue             500       600                                  1.100
4   COGS                -40       -30                                    -70
5   Gross Profit        460       570        0        0        0       1.030
6   
7   OPEX                -10       -12                                    -22
8   Interests           -20       -50                                    -70
9
8   EBT                 430       508        0        0        0         938
```

Formulas:

```
Row 5 = SUMS of Row 3 and Row 4
Row 8 = SUMS of Row 5, Row 7 and Row 8
Column G = SUMS of Columns B to H
```

The spreadsheet shows the performance of a company per month.

Each time a new month is reached I want to copy the values from the last month to the new month. Therefore, I need to identify the first empty column.
I tried to go with the VBA solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096878/automatically-adjust-range-in-vba-to-the-last-empty-column):

```
Sub Last_Used_Column()
c = Sheet1.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox c
End Sub
```

The issue is now, that in contrast to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096878/automatically-adjust-range-in-vba-to-the-last-empty-column) question I have a new **Column G** which displays the total performance.
Therefore, with the above code I will get **Colum H** as result but I want to have **Column D** to be identified as the first empty column.

I think a solution might be to limit the range in which the VBA should look for the first empty column to `Columns B:F`.

How do I have to change the above code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Dim c As Long
c = Sheet1.Cells(3, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

It uses this

```
c = Sheet1.Cells(3, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
```

to find the last used column (in your example G). Then it goes one column left

```
.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)
```

and finds again the last used column (starting from there)

```
.End(xlToLeft).Column
```

finally you can use  `c + 1` to get the empty column right of the last used column.

---

Note: If there are no empty columns then `c` will be `1` so you can easily test this:

```
If c = 1 Then
    MsgBox "No empty columns found", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Hi Peh, Thanks for the code but somehow I get runtime error 424 when I try to rund it on my file.

Comment: @Michi Well, I tested it with the data in your example. So test it with  **exactly** this data.

Comment: I found the issue. Now it'ts running perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the last used col in row 3, then `+1` for the blank cell

```
Sheet1.Rows("3").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
```