# Identify the first emtpy column within a fixed range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A         B         C        D       E           G       H       I        J       K
1               2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06    Total             Q1       Q2
2    
3   Revenue        500     600                        1.100             300      700
4   COGS           -40     -30                          -70            -250     -120
5   Gross Profit   460     570       0        0       1.030              50      580
6   
7   OPEX           -10     -12                          -22             -25     -80
8   Interests      -20     -50                          -70             -30     -95
9
8   EBT            430     508        0        0        938              -5     405
```

Formulas:

```
Row 5 = SUMS of Row 3 and Row 4
Row 8 = SUMS of Row 5, Row 7 and Row 8
Column G = SUMS of Columns B to H
```

The spreadsheet shows the performance of a company per month.

Each time a new month is reached I want to copy the values from the last month to the new month. Therefore, I need to identify the first empty column.
So far I use the solution from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106681/identify-the-first-emtpy-column-within-a-certain-range-using-vba):

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Long
c = Sheet1.Cells(3, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(ColumnOffset:=-3).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox c
    MsgBox c
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, with the above solution I always have to adjust the `ColumnOffset:=-3` in case I add a new Column after `Column J`.

Therefore I would prefer to have a **fixed range** in which the VBA identifies the first empty column. In the case above I would like to give the range `A3:G3` as a search range to the VBA and within this range the first empty column should be identified.

What do I have to change in the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use named ranges. Add a name for your column G and eg. Name it `TotalColumn`.

Then you can use this total column like `Range("TotalColumn")` no matter wich column number or lette it is `Range("TotalColumn")` will always refer to your total column.

Use this to go left from there.

```
c = Sheet1.Cells(3, Range("TotalColumn").Column).End(xlToLeft).Column
```